# create unique IDs for selects in drop zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I realize this question is similar to others posted, but I was hoping someone could help me to approach this problem:

I have a `select` element within a droppable item using JQuery drag-drop which is cloned when dragged. The element has an ID `select` but I need the ID to be unique so I can access the different selected options per box in the drop zone.

[image]

## Below the drag and drop zone you see the select boxes IDs, my desired output is `select_1`, `select_2`, `select_3` etc etc whenever new blocks are dragged

Right now, there is one original select box on the left with the id "select" and I want to dynamically create IDs for the select boxes in the drop zone.

## I was wondering what the best way would be to give each select box within the drop zone it's own unique ID?

That way I can eventually extract the selected values (TWO, THREE, TWO, THREE as in photo above)

## Desired Output

```
select_1     TWO
select_2     THREE
select_3     TWO
select_4     THREE
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dragOpts = {
      helper: 'clone',
      zIndex: 10
    },
    dropOpts = {
      tolerance: 'fit',
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass('div-source')) {
          var cloneDiv = ui.draggable.clone(),
            cloneDragOpts = {
              containment: 'parent'
            };
          cloneDiv.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top,
            left: ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left
          }).draggable(cloneDragOpts);
          $(this).append(cloneDiv);
        }
      }
    };

  $('#source div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).draggable(dragOpts);
  });

  $('#target').droppable(dropOpts);
});

/*
Experimenting with printing the new select IDs
Once dragged into the drop zone
*/
function drop(event) {
  $("#target select").attr("id", (index, oldId) => oldId + "_" + (index + 1))
  var IDs = $("#target select[id]")
    .map(function() {
      return this.id;
    })
    .get();
  document.getElementById("inside_drop_zone").innerHTML = IDs.join(", ")
}
```

```css
#source {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #696969;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

#target {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #696969;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#source div,
#target div {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 70px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</script>
<div id="source">
  <div id="div1" class="div-source">
    <select id="selection">
      <option>ONE</option>
      <option>TWO</option>
      <option>THREE</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="target" ondrop="drop(event)">
</div>

<div id="inside_drop_zone"></div>
```

I realize this post has overlap with others, but I was curious if I'm even going about this the best way and if there are any better suggestions to creating dynamic select boxes.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I strongly suggest you not use ids for this.  You can easily get all the selects in the drop zone with something like `document.querySelector("#inside_drop_zone select")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need them to have unique ID's, ditch the default ID's entirely and add them by doing something like this:

```
let sels = $('#target').children('select');
for (let x = 0; x < sels.length; x++) {
  $(sels[x]).attr('id', 'select_' + x);
}
```

However those ID's won't necessarily be consistent if you rerun this code.